# In XSD schema definition, how to create an array of another custom defined type inside a type definition?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a address type,

```
<xs:complexType name="AddressType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
        <xs:element name="pincode" type="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

How to create a PERSON type which includes an array of Address Type
Something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>
        <xs:element name="addresses">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="address" type="AddressType" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded"/>    
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>   
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

Am I doing it the right way ?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you showed? Because that is how you should do it, except that the `type` attribute should be in the targetNamespace, i.e. `xx:AddressType`, if you has `xmlns:xx="http://mytargetnamespace"`. You can see that it works by simply pasting your code in any (free/commercial) XSD editor (PS: in XML Schema there are no arrays, only sequences... ;)

Comment: @Abel I'm not sure whether this is the right way of doing. That's why I posted the question. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Abel, just to clarify, technically **any** repeating particle (e.g. a repeating choice) is an array; unless you're saying an array is a sequence (in general, not the with the meaning implied by XSD); and one doesn't have to prefix the type if the schema has no target namespace, or if the default namespace of the XML document (that XSD is) matches the targetNamespace of the XSD. In fact, the latter is considered a **best practice** in schema authoring.

Comment: @PetruGardea, not sure what you mean with _"technically"_ here, but XSD and any XML-based language I know of does not mention arrays, because it'd be an implementation detail (and generally, in tree structures, do you really ever talk of arrays?). In fact, the XSD specification only mentions the word "array" once. Do you have a reference of this "best practice", because I agree that I should've written "must be in the target namespace", but I disagree that this is "best practice", and a quick look on W3C normative schema's shows the opposite...

Comment: @Abel... hmmm... in terms of best practice, most of the schemas I've worked with, and I refer here to one available publicly, use xmlns = targetNamespace. Have a look at XHTML, [these guidelines](http://www.medbiq.org/std_specs/techguidelines/xmldesignguidelines.pdf), ACORD's, IFX's, FpML's, FHIR, etc. [here](http://www.xfront.com/DefaultNamespace.html) the editor's node is "preferring" the same...

Comment: (cont'd) Of course there are some, even a significant some maybe, that don't follow (e.g. WSDL, SOAP, etc.) The problem I have is that many papers (XFron's included) are missing scenarios which make the xmlns=targetNamespace way better (if only from an authoring perspective); e.g. changing target namespaces, or moving content to a chameleon schema, or assigning a namespace to a schema at some later point. As for the array part... it is clear (at least to me) the meaning the asker assigned to the word "array"... what do you call a repeating choice? A sequence? ;)

Comment: @Petru, Well, I guess we looked at different schema's from W3C. You refer to XFront, which says ["There is no clear-cut best approach..."](http://www.xfront.com/DefaultNamespace.html). I would call `xs:choice` a _choice-group_, but the official term is a _Model Group_ with an (un)bounded *particle*. You often see this in the [Unique Particle Attribution error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution). _Model Group_ is the term for any group. _Sequence_ is any number of items. And yes, _array_ is an understandable term, but not very precise and from another "world" ;)...